# Pre-built SET environment variable doesn't work

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I am currently trying to make an application that uses a pre-built with visual studio.

As my commands, I have many thats uses the same part of commands, let's say :

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted C:folder1\bin\something.exe "variable1" "variable2"
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted C:folder1\bin\something.exe "variable1" "variable2"
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted C:folder1\bin\something.exe "variable1" "variable2"
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted C:folder1\bin\something.exe "variable2" "variable4"
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted C:folder1\bin\something.exe "variable3" "variable5"
```

I want to set a variable at the top that takes what doesn't change, so: `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted C:folder1\bin\something.exe`

I am currently doing this :

```
SET VAR = powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted C:folder1\bin\something.exe

and trying to call it this way : 

VAR "variable1" "variable2"

VAR "variable1" "variable2"

VAR "variable1" "variable2"

VAR "variable2" "variable4"

VAR "variable3" "variable5"
```

> But this won't work, any heads up why?

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, SET VAR="something"

Must be no spaces between the "="

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling powershell just to call another Executable? Why not just call the executable outright and skip the Powershell layer?

```
SET VAR="C:folder1\bin\something.exe"

VAR "variable1" "variable2"

VAR "variable1" "variable2"

VAR "variable1" "variable2"

VAR "variable2" "variable4"

VAR "variable3" "variable5"
```

Comment: I had to verify if the the executable was up to date within my script and and don't compile it if it was. I thought the best way to to it was by making a powershell script. Do you have anyway better idea ?